# bind zmq dealer to multiple repliers

Tags: asynchronous, routes, zeromq, distributed-computing, server

I want to create a proxy server which routes incoming packets from `REQ` type sockets to one of the `REP` sockets on one of the computers in a cluster. I have been reading the guide and I think the proper structure is a combination of `ROUTER` and `DEALER` on the proxy server. Where the `ROUTER` passes messages to the dealer to be distributed. However, I cannot figure out how to create this connection scheme. Is this the correct architecture? If so how to I bind a dealer to multiple addresses. The flow I envision is like this `REQ->ROUTER|DEALER->[REP, REP, ...]` where only one `REP` socket would handle a single request.

Comment: I use a majordomo pattern two set of borker/workers. On front of them i have put nginix and uses round robin to load balance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### NB: forget about packets -- think in terms of "Behaviour", that's the key

ZeroMQ is rather an abstract layer for certain communication-behavioral patterns, so while terms alike socket do sound similar to what one has read/used previously, the ZeroMQ-world is by far different from many points of view.

This very formalism allows ZeroMQ Formal-Communication-Patterns to grow in scale, to get assembled in higher-order-patterns ( for load-balancing, for fault-tolerance, for performance-scaling ). Mastering this style of thinkign, you forget about packets, thread-sync-issues, I/O-polling and focus on your higher-abstraction-based design -- on **Behaviour** -- rather than on underlying details. This makes your design both free from re-inventing wheel & very powerful, as you re-use a highly professional tools right for your problem-domain tasks.

### DEALER->[REP,REP,...] Segment

That said, your **`DEALER`**-node ( in fact a ZMQsocket-access-node, having **The Behaviour** called a "`DEALER`" to resemble it's queue/buffering-style, it's round-robin dispatcher, it's send-out&expect-answer-in model ) may **`.bind()`** to multiple **`localhost`** **`address:port`**-s and these "service-points" may also operate over different **`TransportClass`**-es -- one working over **`tcp://`**, another over **`inproc://`**, if that makes sense for your Design Architecture -- ZeroMQ empowers you to use this transparently abstracted from all the "awfull&dangerous" lower level gritty-nitties.

### ZeroMQ also allows to reverse .connect() / .bind()

In principle, where helpfull, one may reverse the **`.bind()`** and **`.connect()`** from **`DEALER`** to a known target address of the respective **`REP`** entity.

Comment: In my broker, I binded the Dealer socket to two TCP ports, and in the server the ZMQ REP socket was connected to both the dealer TCP ports, when i fire request from two REQ clients simultaneously, it is not executing parallely, the task is not distributed. please help

Answer (score 2):

You leave a couple details out that are important to determining the correct architecture.

- When you say "from REQ type sockets to one of the REP sockets on one of the computers in a cluster", how do you determine *which* computer gets the message? Is it addressed to a specific computer? Does a computer announce its availability before it can receive a message? Does each message just get passed to the next one in line in a round-robin fashion? **(if it's not the last one, you probably don't want a DEALER socket)**
- When you say "how do I bind a dealer to multiple addresses", it's not clear what you mean by "addresses"... Do you mean to say that the proxy has a unique IP address that it uses to communicate with each computer in the cluster? Or are you just wondering how to manage the connection to multiple different peers with the same socket? The former is a special case, the latter is simple.

I'm going to work with the following assumptions:

1. You want a worker computer from the cluster to announce its availability for work before it receives any work, and any computer in the cluster can handle any job.  A faster worker, or a worker working on a smaller job, will not have to wait behind some slow worker to finish their job and get a new job first.
2. The proxy/broker uses a single ip interface to communicate with all workers.

If those are true, then what you want will be closer to this:

```
REQ->ROUTER|ROUTER->[REQ, REQ, ...]
```

A worker will create a request to the backend router socket to announce its availability, and await a reply with work.  Once it is finished, it will create a new request with the finished work, which again announces its availability.  The other half of the pattern you've already worked out.

This is the [Simple Pirate Pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Basic-Reliable-Queuing-Simple-Pirate-Pattern) from the ZMQ guide.  It's a good place to start, but it's not very robust.  This is in the Reliable Request-Reply Patterns section of the guide, and I suggest you read or reread that section carefully as it will guide you well.  In particular, they keep refining this pattern into more and more reliable implementations and wind up with the Majordomo pattern, which is very robust and fault tolerant.  You should see if you need all the features that provides or if you can scale it back a little.  Either way, you should learn and understand what these patterns are doing and why before you make the choice to do something different.